# How do I create a sourcemap for each individual js file with grunt-contrib-concat and grunt-contrib-uglify?

Tags: gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

Currently, the concat and uglify settings are:

```
concat: {
  options: {
    // options
  },
  angular: {
    src: ['public/**/*.js', '!public/**/*.min.js', '!public/lib/**/*.js'],
    dest: 'build/_main.js',
  }
},

uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false,
    sourceMap: true,
  },
  app: {
    files: {
      'public/js/app.min.js': ['build/_main.js']
    }
  },
  bower: {
    files: {
      'public/js/lib.min.js': ['build/_bower.js']
    }
  }
},
```

This creates one source map in the dev tools under Sources. This source map is usable but I would way rather be able to search file by file and navigate through every file in the dev tools. It would be nice if the entire project directory and file structure was preserved so I could search and navigate through each file and add debuggers, etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by configuring your tasks as follows:

***Note:** Both solutions below will require the `concat` task to be run before the `uglify` task.*

---

#### 1. Using default generated names for source maps:

```js
concat: {
  options: {
    sourceMap: true // <-- 1. Enable source maps
  },
  angular: {
    src: ['public/**/*.js', '!public/**/*.min.js', '!public/lib/**/*.js'],
    dest: 'build/_tsbc.js',
  }
},

uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false,
    sourceMap: true,
    sourceMapIn: './build/_tsbc.js.map' // <-- 2. Define .map file to use.
  },
  app: {
    files: {
      'public/js/app.min.js': ['build/_tsbc.js']
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

**Explanation**

1. In your `concat` task you need to firstly set the [`sourceMap`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#sourcemap) option to `true`. Given your current configuration this will create a source map file at the following path:

   `build/_tsbc.js.map`

   *Note: the location of the generated map file defaults to the same `dest` path as defined in the `angular` target of the `concat` task - with the additional `.map` suffix appended.*
2. Then in your `uglify` task add the [`sourceMapIn`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#sourcemapin) option and set its value (String) to the path of the `.map` file generated at stage one above. I.e.

   ```js
   sourceMapIn: './build/_tsbc.js.map'
   ```

---

#### 2. Explicitly defined names for source maps:

It's also possible to define the specific name and path for the source map file generated by the `concat` task. For example:

```js
concat: {
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,  // <-- 1. Enable source maps
    sourceMapName: 'build/my_map.map'  // <-- 2. Specify output path
  },
  angular: {
    src: ['public/**/*.js', '!public/**/*.min.js', '!public/lib/**/*.js'],
    dest: 'build/_tsbc.js',
  }
},

uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false,
    sourceMap: true,
    sourceMapIn: './build/my_map.map'  // <-- 3. Define .map file to use.
  },
  app: {
    files: {
      'public/js/app.min.js': ['build/_tsbc.js']
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

**Explanation**

1. Same as before, set the [`sourceMap`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#sourcemap) option to `true`
2. This time, add the [`sourceMapName`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#sourcemapname) option and specify the path of the generated source map.

   *Note: the location of the generated map file is now set to:*

   `'build/my_map.map'`
3. Again, in your `uglify` task add the [`sourceMapIn`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#sourcemapin) option and set its value to the same path specified in the previous point. I.e.

   ```js
   sourceMapIn: './build/my_map.map'
   ```

---

**EDIT**

I've just noticed that your `bower` target in the `uglify` task does not depend on output from the previous `concat` task. For this scenario you'll need to nest the `options` object in each target. For example:

```js
uglify: {
  app: {
    options: {  // <-- Specific options for `app` target 
      mangle: false,
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapIn: './build/my_map.map'  // <-- 3. Define .map file to use.
    },
    files: {
      'public/js/app.min.js': ['build/_tsbc.js']
    }
  },
  bower: {
    options: {  // <-- Specific options for `bower` target 
      mangle: false,
      sourceMap: true
      // <-- There's no `sourceMapIn` needed here.
    },
    files: {
      'public/js/lib.min.js': ['build/_bower.js']
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Really strong explanation. I ended up figuring it out previously using your first solution but you definitely explained it well.